# Applying "this" to a specific parents other child using Jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this basic layout. Where if you click "learn more" it should reveal more description text in the box by adding a class that changes its display property.

However usually i will use "closest" or "this" snippets if its a direct child of the clickable element but im having trouble finding this one in the dom.

How can i make each "learn more" button open up the correct text below it without opening the others/all at once?

**I can not change the html markup.**

Thanks!

```js
$(function() {
    $('.learn-more-btn').click(function() {
        $('.item-learn-more-popup').toggleClass("active");
    });
});
```

```css
.item-learn-more-popup {
    display:none;
}
.item-learn-more-popup.active{
  display:block;
}







.items-and-stuffs {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.item {
  padding:40px;
  margin:10px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 100px);
  background:#e4e4e4;
}
h2{
  margin-top:0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
}

a.learn-more-btn {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 88px;
    pointer:cursor;
    border-radius:90px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.item-learn-more-popup {
    margin-top: 17px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .item {
    padding:40px;
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .item {
    padding:40px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-and-stuffs">
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 1</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item one... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item one... This is more info about item one. Where we      go into more details about this item
   </div> 
</div> 
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 2</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item two... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item two... This is more info about item two. Where we      go into more details about this item
   </div>
</div> 
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 3</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item three... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item three... This is more info about item three. Where      we go into more details about this item
   </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 4</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item four... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item four... This is more info about item four. Where        we go into more details about this item
   </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 5</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item five... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item five... This is more info about item five. Where        we go into more details about this item
   </div> 
 </div>
                
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `find()` with `closest()`

**closest()**

1. Begins with the current element
2. Travels up the DOM tree until it finds a match for the supplied selector
3. The returned jQuery object contains zero or one element for each element in the original set, in document order

```js
$('.learn-more-btn').click(function() {
  $(this).closest('.item').find('.item-learn-more-popup').toggleClass("active");
});
```

```css
.item-learn-more-popup {
  display: none;
}

.item-learn-more-popup.active {
  display: block;
}

.items-and-stuffs {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.item {
  padding: 40px;
  margin: 10px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 100px);
  background: #e4e4e4;
}

h2 {
  margin-top: 0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
}

a.learn-more-btn {
  border: 1px solid gray;
  background: gray;
  color: white;
  padding: 10px 13px;
  display: block;
  text-align: center;
  max-width: 88px;
  pointer: cursor;
  border-radius: 90px;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.item-learn-more-popup {
  margin-top: 17px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .item {
    padding: 40px;
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .item {
    padding: 40px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-and-stuffs">
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        <h2>Item 1</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>This is item one... This is mo...</p>
      </div>
      <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
      This is item one... This is more info about item one. Where we go into more details about this item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        <h2>Item 2</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>This is item two... This is mo...</p>
      </div>
      <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
      This is item two... This is more info about item two. Where we go into more details about this item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        <h2>Item 3</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>This is item three... This is mo...</p>
      </div>
      <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
      This is item three... This is more info about item three. Where we go into more details about this item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        <h2>Item 4</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>This is item four... This is mo...</p>
      </div>
      <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
      This is item four... This is more info about item four. Where we go into more details about this item
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <div class="item-content">
      <div>
        <h2>Item 5</h2>
      </div>
      <div>
        <p>This is item five... This is mo...</p>
      </div>
      <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div>
    </div>
    <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
      This is item five... This is more info about item five. Where we go into more details about this item
    </div>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is, that you are selecting all instances of `.item-learn-more-popup`. If you only want to select the nearest instance of the popup, you need to go up the DOM and then back down. You could do this with the [`parents()`](https://api.jquery.com/parents) (applied to the clicked element) selector and go up to a common parent. From there you need to go down the tree and find the popup.

```
$('.learn-more-btn').click(function() {
    $(this).parents('.item').find('.item-learn-more-popup').toggleClass('active');
});
```

And here is your adapted example:

```js
$(function() {
    $('.learn-more-btn').click(function() {
        $(this).parents('.item').find('.item-learn-more-popup').toggleClass('active');
    });
});
```

```css
.item-learn-more-popup {
    display:none;
}
.item-learn-more-popup.active{
  display:block;
}

.items-and-stuffs {
  display:flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
.item {
  padding:40px;
  margin:10px;
  width: calc(33.33% - 100px);
  background:#e4e4e4;
}
h2{
  margin-top:0;
  margin-block-start: 0;
}

a.learn-more-btn {
    border: 1px solid gray;
    background: gray;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px 13px;
    display: block;
    text-align: center;
    max-width: 88px;
    pointer:cursor;
    border-radius:90px;
    cursor:pointer;
}
.item-learn-more-popup {
    margin-top: 17px;
}
@media only screen and (max-width: 950px) {
  .item {
    padding:40px;
    width: calc(50% - 100px);
  }
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 580px) {
  .item {
    padding:40px;
    width: calc(100% - 100px);
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="items-and-stuffs">
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 1</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item one... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item one... This is more info about item one. Where we      go into more details about this item
   </div> 
</div> 
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 2</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item two... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item two... This is more info about item two. Where we      go into more details about this item
   </div>
</div> 
<div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 3</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item three... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item three... This is more info about item three. Where      we go into more details about this item
   </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 4</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item four... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item four... This is more info about item four. Where        we go into more details about this item
   </div> 
 </div> 
 <div class="item">
   <div class="item-content">
     <div><h2>Item 5</h2></div> 
     <div><p>This is item five... This is mo...</p></div>
     <div><a class="learn-more-btn">learn more</a></div> 
   </div> 
   <div class="item-learn-more-popup">
     This is item five... This is more info about item five. Where        we go into more details about this item
   </div> 
 </div>
                
</div>
```